# Can a table be styled like this? Or would something else be better?

Tags: html, css, tabular

Basically I am working on some practices since last week to start learning html and css, and I wanted to create a table of sorts to display items with the option to see more info and take/buy it. I was thinking in adding some background icons or image hence the strange looking table.

My question is. Can something like that be styled or would a normal table be better? To illustrate my point I did a mockup of sorts.

Oh! And as not to make another question just for that, can a dropdown list be made to have checkboxs without using jQuery? I'm afraid that is completely out of my reach with my current knowledge.

http://i59.tinypic.com/25z47dh.png

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance
Best Wishes

Comment: The simply answer your first question... Yes, it can be styled like that.

Comment: The simply answer your second question... Yes, it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

You may use `display: table` and assign table 'rows' and 'columns' on div tags.

Or

You may use `float: left` which will line everything like a table and be more responsive.

Or

You may use `display: inline-block` which will behave a lot like the floats except you get a little bit more control on box height.

There is no correct answer here but my preference is with `inline-block` since browser support tends to be superior than floats while keeping everything responsive.

Comment: But that be cumbersome when a new item has to be added? I mean for what I understood you are saying that I should do a big div and add little divs with the information and display those inline right? I'm kinda new, sorry if I didn't catch it right, and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, if you want to stay truly responsive and nimble you can simply line them up side-to-side. As the window grows / shrinks you'll get a number of items per row. I know for a fact you can achieve this with `inline-block` and `float` not sure about `table` though.

Comment: Oh and for the checkboxed dropdown you'll have to use jQuery to apply the filter. You are really looking at a customized input element since this is not supported in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Beautifulcoder! At the risk of inducing hair pulls and even facepalms, could I get a example of how would that look?

Comment: Yeah, I resigned myself to learn how to use jQuery for this, because I earched a lot and indeed there where no answers on how to do it in html/css. Oh well!

Comment: Sure, give me some time to crank it out. And yea, you get basic dropdowns, checkboxes, radioboxes and texboxes in vanilla HTML. Anything else is pure custom tailored-made magic.

Comment: Here were [are.](http://jsfiddle.net/beautifulcoder/ax3VL/) I purposely collapsed the last two boxes to show how you can line them up perfectly by removing white space in between div tags. Keep in mind this is not production worthy but a simply demo.

Comment: Thanks! If I were to add this inside a div would it behave like in the fiddle? For all intents and purposes this is what I needed, so I was thinking in adding that code to the big div and float it right, so the combobox would stay left. Argh! I am totally rubbish at positioning.

Comment: Chrome displays it like this: http://i62.tinypic.com/4uz1o2.png